# Is there a type that includes strings and lists in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Right now I'm trying to make a basic function that removes any spaces or commas from a sentence.

```
stringToIntList :: [Char] -> [Char]
stringToIntList inpt = [ a | a <- inpt, a `elem` [" ",","]]
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that every type I've tried doesn't work, if I put [Char] it freaks out at commas, if I put [string] it freaks out at spaces, and if I put string it just doesn't recognize a and says it's an error. so I was wondering if there was some type that could work as both a [Char] and a [string].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the current type, the definition needs to be

```
stringToIntList inpt = [ a | a <- inpt, a `elem` [' ',',']]
```

(single quotes, because these are `Char` literals, not `String` ones!),
or alternatively

```
stringToIntList inpt = [ a | a <- inpt, a `elem` " ,"]
```

(using the fact that a string is just a list of characters),
or simply

```
stringToIntList = filter (`elem` " ,")
```

Note that this doesn't *remove* spaces and commas, on the contrary those are the only characters it *keeps*. To remove them instead, you need to invert the predicate:

```
stringToIntList = filter $ not . (`elem` " ,")
```

As Iceland_jack comments, there is actually a standard function for this combination:

```
stringToIntList = filter (`notElem` " ,")
```

If you really did want `` a `elem` [" ",","] `` then the type of your function would need to be

```
stringToIntList :: [String] -> [String]
```

or equivalently `[[Char]] -> [[Char]]`.

Comment: there is a `notElem = not . elem` function, it would be nice to have `keep = filter` and `drop = (>>> not) >>> filter` if that name wasn't taken